# SMOTE in ML classifcation

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I am running a classification algorithm in Jupyter, using sklearn.
I want to use SMOTE, since one of my groups is only 35% of the other 2 groups. So I want to oversample that group (group 1) but I don't know how to integrate it. (Edit: I know about the SMOTE script, but i want to know where it fits in my script below).
Help?

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split (X, y, test_size = 0.1) 
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform (X_test)
from sklearn.svm import SVC
clf = SVC(kernel = 'linear')
clf.fit (X_train, y_train.ravel())
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
cm = confusion_matrix (y_test, y_pred)
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
accuracies = cross_val_score (estimator = clf, X = X_train, y = y_train, cv = 10)
accuracies.mean()
accuracies.std()
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
parameters = [{'C':[1, 10, 100], 'kernel':['linear']}, 
              {'C':[1, 10, 100], 
               'kernel':['rbf'], 
               'gamma': [0.05, 0.001,　0.005]}]
grid_search = GridSearchCV (estimator = clf, param_grid = parameters, scoring = 'accuracy', cv = 10)
grid_search = grid_search.fit (X_train,y_train)
best_accuracy =  grid_search.best_score_ 
print (best_accuracy)
best_parameters = grid_search.best_params_
print (best_parameters)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do SMOTE on your dataset and use the resulting balanced dataset for training you model.

So, you have to load  the data as you do in your code which is not shown in the question and apply SMOTE on it.

In terms of code it can be done like this

```
X = # train data
y = # train labels

# applying SMOTE

from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE

sm = SMOTE(random_state=42)
X_balanced, y_balanced = sm.fit_sample(X, y)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split (X_balanced, y_balanced, test_size = 0.1) 
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform (X_test)
from sklearn.svm import SVC
clf = SVC(kernel = 'linear')
clf.fit (X_train, y_train.ravel())
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
cm = confusion_matrix (y_test, y_pred)
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
accuracies = cross_val_score (estimator = clf, X = X_train, y = y_train, cv = 10)
accuracies.mean()
accuracies.std()
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
parameters = [{'C':[1, 10, 100], 'kernel':['linear']}, 
              {'C':[1, 10, 100], 
               'kernel':['rbf'], 
               'gamma': [0.05, 0.001,　0.005]}]
grid_search = GridSearchCV (estimator = clf, param_grid = parameters, scoring = 'accuracy', cv = 10)
grid_search = grid_search.fit (X_train,y_train)
best_accuracy =  grid_search.best_score_ 
print (best_accuracy)
best_parameters = grid_search.best_params_
print (best_parameters)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SMOTE](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/imbalanced-learn/stable/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.SMOTE.html) from [imbalanced learn](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/imbalanced-learn/stable/index.html) like this

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE

sm = SMOTE(random_state=42)
X_balanced, y_balanced = sm.fit_sample(X, y) #where X and y are your original features and labels
```

Then use `X_balanced` and `y_balanced` as your `X` and `y` respectively

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. Maybe my questions is not clear. I want to know how to integrate SMOTE in my script. I know about the script for smote but i don't know where i can add it in my script. I edited my Q.

Comment: After you loaded the dataset do smote like this and do the rest as same

Answer (score 1):

You may separate your data into train and test before doing SMOTE to avoid overfitting.
The right way: oversampling only the training data. https://beckernick.github.io/oversampling-modeling/